# What are the benefits of mounting an engine above the fuselage?

Tags: engine, airplane

I'm wondering what advantage/disadvantage, if any, does mounting an engine **above the fuselage** give? This question comes up after seeing the **Macchi M.33** below:
[image: A Black-and-White image of an Italian Macchi M.33 floating on the water using its buoyant fuselage, with the engine visibly mounted above the fuselage on struts.]

The engine mounted in such a way does look interesting, but I'm wondering if it might make the plane want to dip down slightly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you mean, *other than* the obvious one of keeping the propeller out the water and spray?

Comment: Clearly, yes. But I'm talking about benefits to flight.

Comment: Given that you only see this configuration on seaplanes you may want to ask what the drawbacks are.

Comment: @GdD The Boeing 727 wasn't a seaplane, and it had one of its engines in a similar position.

Comment: Not really @nick012000, on the 727 it was far closer to axis of the airplane.

Comment: @nick012000, don't confuse the intake with the engine:  The middle engine of the 727 was about as far above the axis as the F-16 engine is below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's strictly to stay clear of spray in seaplanes, or because the engine was tacked on as an afterthought for some reason (like a motorglider conversion) and that was the only place to put it.

There aren't any aerodynamic benefits, or you would see the configuration on landplanes.

You've increased the frontal area by having a big pod sticking out.  The high thrust line wants to pitch the airplane over, increasing tail trimming forces required to compensate, and hence drag. There there are the undesirable handling qualities, mainly a strong pitch down tendency when you add power quickly, and worse, a pitch up tendency when you remove power quickly, which can get the unawares into quite a lot of trouble.

So to summarize, sticking an engine there is only done when there's nowhere else to put it.

Comment: "There aren't any aerodynamic benefits, or you would see the configuration on landplanes." The Boeing 727 has one engine like this.

Comment: No the engine is in the tail cone.  The intake is an S duct.  The DC-10 is closer to your point, but the engine is right on top of the fuselage, not sticking way up on a pylon in order to clear a propeller.  Irrelevant for the purpose of the question.

Comment: It's still mounted above the fuselage, which is what the question's about. It's not as far above the fuselage, proportionally, but it's still above it.

Comment: @nick012000 A better example would be the Heinkel 162. But the last sentence of the answer sums it up nicely and applies to all examples.

Comment: “There aren't any aerodynamic benefits, or you would see the configuration on landplanes.“ Non-sequitur. It could conceivable be that there are benefits, but only small ones that are outweighed by disadvantages of safety, maintenance etc..

Comment: @PeterKämpf note that we're talking about placing the engine several feet above the fuselage as in the OP's picture. In the case of the 162, it's still sub optimal, but the pitch effects of the only slightly elevated thrust line is much milder, and I have read that the 162 had pretty good handing qualities considering its squirrelly appearance. The CRJs I flew had slightly above the CG thrust lines and there were detectable trim changes with power if you were observing. On the case of the DC-10, the tail engine would be beneficial in countering the pitching effects of the wing engines.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If you had an airplane with the engine in a more ideal location, and asked if there could be any aerodynamic or behavioural improvement moving it to the top of a pylon several feet up above, I can tell you that the answer is no, nada, nothing, zip, waste of time.  The expression "you would see the configuration on landplanes" is a practical proof that a 100 years of designing agrees that that is the case.  Same as with canards.  If they really were superior, after all that promotion by Rutan, they would be everywhere, not an oddity.

Comment: @nick012000: WRT the 727, DC-10, and similar, the problem that tail-mounted engine is addressing is where the heck are you supposed to stick a 3rd engine?  Regulations meant you had to have at least 3 for over-water flights, 4 got you into size & cost territory.  So you traded off the disadvantages of things like S-ducts and more complicated tail structure for the advantages of the 3rd engine.

Comment: @nick012000 - better examples for the point you're trying to make would be the DC-10 or MD-11, where the third engine actually was mounted above the fuselage, as part of the vertical stabilizer structure. However, in both the 727 and L-1011 the third engine is mounted fore-and-after inside the the fuselage and an S-shaped duct is used to supply air to it.

Comment: I'm surprised I haven't seen the A-10 mentioned here. The reason for the high-mounted engines isn't because there's nowhere else to put them, nor is it for ground clearance.

Comment: @CareyGregory The post is about engines placed WAY above the fuselage, on pylons meant to clear propellers, mostly on seaplanes, not jet engines and turbofans engines mounted slightly above at the tail.  The A10 isn't much different from any business jet like the Challenger (which has the same engines) where the engines are slightly above the vertical CG and aerodynamic center.

Comment: @JohnK Okay, but I didn't see that much specificity in the question. It seemed quite broad.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I believe the reason for the somewhat high placement of the A-10 engines on the fuselage is to allow the tailplanes to help hide the infrared signature of the exhaust from ground-fired missiles.

Answer (score 5):

Many light-sport airplanes and ultralight airplanes have a high-wing configuration with a high-mounted pusher engine behind the pilot.  Here the engine is above most or all of what one would normally define as the "fuselage", including the tail boom.  One advantage of this configuration is that it gives the pilot a more unobstructed view in the forward direction.

Examples:

Challenger ultralight

Bailey-Moyes Dragonfly

Sportflight Talon

MX Quicksilver

Comment: These configurations have the wings as main drag source in line with thrust, and hence avoid the the pitch-down torque of the M.33 in the picture. Plus, design criteria in Ultralights are really different to "normal planes" (pilot positioning affects cg a lot, focus on forgiving flight behavior over aerodynamic efficiency .. )

Comment: Again, these aircraft have engines SLIGHTLY high, not way up on a pylon.

Answer (score 4):

The main purpose is, of course, avoid that the propeller hits the water (or ground).

In the other hand the thrust is applied above the CG point of the aircraft. This introduce a considerable moment arm that, translated in manovrability, means an unwished tendence of the plane to dive when the power is suddenly increased.

So we add a little *pitch angle up* on the engine pod.  Because the prop is forward of the CG, this helps counter-act the nose down torque of the high mount when thrust is applied.

The advantage is to counter-act the tendency of a plane to *climb* when thrust is applied.  Many aircraft have *down thrust angle* even when the motor is mounted in front of the fuselage near the center of gravity, rather than above it.

In design, this plane is essentially a low wing PBY Catalina.  Amazingly, it was bested in the 1925 Schneider Cup races by two biplanes: the Gloster IIIA and the Curtiss RC3-2 (flown by none other than Jimmy Dolittle).  It could not be raced at full throttle due to wing flutter issues.

Macchi would go on to set a speed record for *all piston aircraft* with the M.C. 72 at 440 mph in 1934, a record that would stand for 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the usual floats.

Floats obviously add both weight and drag so it is beneficial to fly without them. With the fuselage sailing like a ship, they are not required. There are some under the wings but tiny. They do not support the full weight of the aircraft.

But floats also keep the aircraft in expected orientation, raised above the water, same as it would be raised above the ground. Without them, the traditional place for the engine is just too low.